# MinGW doesn't recognize the directory opencv

Tags: opencv, mingw-w64

I write a code using opencv library, I used codeblocks ide configuring it to work with opencv (configuring linker settings and search directory and including all the necesary path to enviroment variable) correctly and then the program works fine. The problem is when I try to compile using minGW with g++ 6.3.0 version, it gave me the next error:

```
ImgSeg.cpp:2:39: fatal error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or 
directory
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
                                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

I try all possible form to put the opencv2 directory in enviroment variable but it has the same error all the time, it's a little frustrating. this is what I have on path in enviroment variable:

`C:\opencv_install\lib;
C:\opencv_install\include;
C:\opencv_install\bin;`

I'm using windows 7 64 and opencv 2.4.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could compile the program but I had to install mingw64 version 4.9.2 from this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/). The command that I use to compile was this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 "name of the program.cpp" -IC:/opencv_install/include -LC:/opencv_install/lib -llibopencv_core249 -llibopencv_highgui249 -llibopencv_imgproc249 -o "name of the exe"
```

It's important include the `-l` lib that you used in the program

Answer (score 0):

GCC does not search `PATH` when looking for include files.

You will need to tell it where to look by using the `-I` commandline parameter:

```
-IC:\opencv_install\include
```

When linking, you'll also need to tell GCC where to find the libraries you're linking:

```
-LC:\opencv_install\lib -lopencv_core
```

In CodeBlocks you'll need to add the former to include directories (not `PATH`) in the project settings.

Comment: Thanks for the response @rubenvb but when i wrote g++ -IC:/opencv_install/include ImgSeg.cpp, give a lot of erros of deprecated declarations and undefined reference. Here is a link of small screenshot of the errors [link](https://gyazo.com/e57440ecda4aa54576ffa7967d073c46)

Comment: The deprecated warnings you'll have to turn off or ignore. The linker errors are because you're not linking the OpenCV libraries. I don't know enough about OpenCV to tell you directly which ones you need to link. This here in the OpenCV documentation might help: https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/d52/tutorial_windows_install.html